How can I have the maximum maxzoom possible with custom styles in google maps api?
I use custom styles in Google Api. In my location (Netherlands I can zoom until 22 with default google maps api maps. But when I add custom styles as simple als the following I can zoom max until 20.And if I switch to default Satelite I can zoom to max 21.
How can I make sure I can zoom until 22?
Custom style:
styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
  [
    {
      featureType: 'landscape.man_made',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }]
    },
  ],
  { name: 'Kaart' }
);

I tried setting maxZoom: 22 and searched a lot on blogs and these kind of forms but no solution found yet. I should be simple right?
